# Como remover acentuação usando bat/cmd

Tags: script, cmd, batch, bat

Como criar pasta usando nome de um usuário sem o(s) acento(s) ou caractere(s) especiais?

Como por exemplo, trocando ***`càmbio`*** para ***`cambio`***

Existe algum comando que converta isso?

Agradeço!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Sem precisar de dependências/linguagens externas** você pode usar um simples "replace", claro que isto teria que rodar em `windows-1252` e tudo teria que ser configurando desta maneira.

### Replace em CMD/BAT

```
set STR=Boa noite!
call set STR=%%STR:noite=tarde%%
echo %STR%
```

Isto `%%STR:noite=tarde%%` troca a palavra noite por tarde da variavel `STR`

### Remover acentos (windows-1252)

Para trocar os acentos crie um `.bat` e salve como ANSI ou windows-1252 (compatível) e então para um teste simples coloque isto (não contém todos acentos, mas é apenas um exemplo de uso):

```
@echo off

chcp 1252>nul

cls

set ORIGINAL=Letra "á", letra "é", letra "í", letra "ó", letra "ú", letra "Á", letra "É", letra "Í", letra "Ó", letra "Ú, letra "ç" e letra "Ç"

set DADOS=%ORIGINAL%

set DADOS=%DADOS:â=a%
set DADOS=%DADOS:Â=A%
set DADOS=%DADOS:à=a%
set DADOS=%DADOS:À=A%
set DADOS=%DADOS:á=a%
set DADOS=%DADOS:Á=A%
set DADOS=%DADOS:ã=a%
set DADOS=%DADOS:Ã=A%
set DADOS=%DADOS:ê=e%
set DADOS=%DADOS:Ê=E%
set DADOS=%DADOS:è=e%
set DADOS=%DADOS:È=E%
set DADOS=%DADOS:é=e%
set DADOS=%DADOS:É=E%
set DADOS=%DADOS:î=i%
set DADOS=%DADOS:Î=I%
set DADOS=%DADOS:ì=i%
set DADOS=%DADOS:Ì=I%
set DADOS=%DADOS:í=i%
set DADOS=%DADOS:Í=I%
set DADOS=%DADOS:õ=o%
set DADOS=%DADOS:Õ=O%
set DADOS=%DADOS:ô=o%
set DADOS=%DADOS:Ô=O%
set DADOS=%DADOS:ò=o%
set DADOS=%DADOS:Ò=O%
set DADOS=%DADOS:ó=o%
set DADOS=%DADOS:Ó=O%
set DADOS=%DADOS:ü=u%
set DADOS=%DADOS:Ü=U%
set DADOS=%DADOS:û=u%
set DADOS=%DADOS:Û=U%
set DADOS=%DADOS:ú=u%
set DADOS=%DADOS:Ú=U%
set DADOS=%DADOS:ù=u%
set DADOS=%DADOS:Ù=U%
set DADOS=%DADOS:ç=c%
set DADOS=%DADOS:Ç=C%

echo Original:

echo %ORIGINAL%

echo -----------------

echo Trocado:

echo %DADOS%

pause
```

---

Pelo que entendi de sua pergunta (criar pasta com o nome de "usuário"), usando o `mkdir` ficaria assim:

```
@echo off

chcp 1252>nul

:: Pega o que o usuário digitar
set /p NOME="Qual seu nome?"

:: Nome da pasta
set NOME_PASTA=%NOME%

set NOME_PASTA=%NOME_PASTA:â=a%
set NOME_PASTA=%NOME_PASTA:Â=A%
set NOME_PASTA=%NOME_PASTA:à=a%
set NOME_PASTA=%NOME_PASTA:À=A%
set NOME_PASTA=%NOME_PASTA:á=a%
set NOME_PASTA=%NOME_PASTA:Á=A%
set NOME_PASTA=%NOME_PASTA:ã=a%
set NOME_PASTA=%NOME_PASTA:Ã=A%
set NOME_PASTA=%NOME_PASTA:ê=e%
set NOME_PASTA=%NOME_PASTA:Ê=E%
set NOME_PASTA=%NOME_PASTA:è=e%
set NOME_PASTA=%NOME_PASTA:È=E%
set NOME_PASTA=%NOME_PASTA:é=e%
set NOME_PASTA=%NOME_PASTA:É=E%
set NOME_PASTA=%NOME_PASTA:î=i%
set NOME_PASTA=%NOME_PASTA:Î=I%
set NOME_PASTA=%NOME_PASTA:ì=i%
set NOME_PASTA=%NOME_PASTA:Ì=I%
set NOME_PASTA=%NOME_PASTA:í=i%
set NOME_PASTA=%NOME_PASTA:Í=I%
set NOME_PASTA=%NOME_PASTA:õ=o%
set NOME_PASTA=%NOME_PASTA:Õ=O%
set NOME_PASTA=%NOME_PASTA:ô=o%
set NOME_PASTA=%NOME_PASTA:Ô=O%
set NOME_PASTA=%NOME_PASTA:ò=o%
set NOME_PASTA=%NOME_PASTA:Ò=O%
set NOME_PASTA=%NOME_PASTA:ó=o%
set NOME_PASTA=%NOME_PASTA:Ó=O%
set NOME_PASTA=%NOME_PASTA:ü=u%
set NOME_PASTA=%NOME_PASTA:Ü=U%
set NOME_PASTA=%NOME_PASTA:û=u%
set NOME_PASTA=%NOME_PASTA:Û=U%
set NOME_PASTA=%NOME_PASTA:ú=u%
set NOME_PASTA=%NOME_PASTA:Ú=U%
set NOME_PASTA=%NOME_PASTA:ù=u%
set NOME_PASTA=%NOME_PASTA:Ù=U%
set NOME_PASTA=%NOME_PASTA:ç=c%
set NOME_PASTA=%NOME_PASTA:Ç=C%

:: Exibe o nome digitado
echo Nome do usuário %NOME%

:: Quebra de linha na tela
echo.

:: Exibe o nome da pasta
echo Nome da pasta %NOME_PASTA%

:: Cria pasta (coloque a pasta)
mkdir "%NOME_PASTA%"
```

Entendo muito pouco de batch/cmd e de Windows, mas creio que talvez com um `for` consiga simplificar, mas o resultado seria basicamente o mesmo resultado. Sobre caracteres mais complexos e variações de codificações o uso de `.bat` por si só já é extremamente complicado e neste caso valeria mais a pena escrever em outra linguagem (se for um script para ajudar em algum trabalho) ou se for criar algo para o usuário final o mesmo mesmo seria criar um "programa de verdade", com uma linguagem que lhe forneça as APIs (bibliotecas) necessárias para facilitar.

Comment: Obgd era disso que eu precisava. Percebi um erro nesse segundo codigo na ultima linha 
mkdir  %NOME_PASTA% o certo seria %DADOS% não ? vlws

Comment: @OProgramador corrigi o exemplo, foi na ultima edição que fiz, agora esta ok. A variavel NOME é o nome do usuario e NOME_PASTA o nome sem acentos para gerar a pasta

Answer (score 2):

Seja bem vindo ao **SO**!

---

Não existe um comando para criar pastas com nome de usuário **sem os acentos!**

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Infelizmente não temos um comando para executar a tarefa de **"remover acentos"** provido pelo sistema operacional em si, mas, o que podemos fazer para a remocer/converter carácteres acentuados, é usar um **`bat`** junto com **`C#`**, e que, em tempo de execução, pode dar o tratamento necessário na remoção dos acentos nas string, e criar a pasta "desacentuadas".

---

Abaixo um **`bat`** que durante sua execução, vai gerar um código **`C#`** para ser usador na tarefa de conversão das strings acentuadas, possibilitando a criação das pastas com os nomes dos usuários do sistema sem os respectivos acentos:

**obs.:** Para usar o **`bat`**, use na mesma pasta onde vais criar as pastas com os nomes, ou, tens que substituir na linha 8, onde tens **`"_path=."`** pelo **`_path=drive\caminho`** onde precisar criar as pastas:

---

```bat
@echo off & setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion 

cd /d "%~dp0" && title >nul && title Q399493 & >nul 2>nul chcp 1252
for /f ^delims^=*^~ %%i in ('%__APPDIR__%\where wmic.exe')do set _wmic=%%~i
set /a "_cnt=0" && set "_p=pathping 127.1 -n -q 1 -p 50" && set "_usr_log=%temp%\tmp_usr_.log"

for /f %%a in ('"prompt $h&for %%b in (0) do rem"')do set "_bs=%%a"
2>nul >nul del /q /f "%temp%\Rm_Acnt.cs" & 2>nul >nul del /q /f "!_usr_log!" 
set "_csc=%windir%\Microsoft.NET" & set "_where=%__appdir__%where.exe" & set "_path=."
set "_arg=/t:exe /out:"%tmp%\Rm_Acnt.exe" "%tmp%\Rm_Acnt.cs" /platform:anycpu /unsafe+ /w:0 /o /nologo"
!_wmic! /append:"!_usr_log!" useraccount where (status='ok') get name /format:list|findstr .>nul

cd /d "%temp%" && >"%temp%\Rm_Acnt.cs"^
    (
     echo/using System;namespace SO_BR_Q399493 ^{class Program ^{static void Main^(string[] args^)^{^{
     echo/byte[] tempBytes; tempBytes = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding^("ISO-8859-8"^).GetBytes^(args[0]^);
     echo/string asciiStr = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString^(tempBytes^);Console.Write^(asciiStr^);^}^}^}^}
    )

for /f  delims^=^ eol^=* %%i in ('!_where! /r "!_csc!" "csc.exe"^|findstr /lic:"k\v2\."')do "%%~i" !_arg!
2>nul >nul !_p! & for /f ^tokens^=2^delims^=^=  %%f in ('type "!_usr_log!"^|findstr .')do set "_str=%%~f" && call :^] 
2>nul >nul del /q /f "%temp%\Rm_Acnt.*" & 2>nul >nul del /q /f "!_usr_log!" & goto :eof

:^]
for /f delims^=^ eol^=* %%B in ('Rm_Acnt.exe "!_str!"')do call cmd /v/c && cmd /v/c mkdir "!_path!%%~B" 2>nul && (
set "_msg=Usuario: "!_str!" Pasta Criada Em: "!_path!%%~B"" )||( set "_msg=Usuario: "!_str!" Pasta Existe: "!_path!%%~B"")
for /f delims^=^ eol^=* %%a in ('"cmd /u /c echo=!_msg!|find /v """')do set /p "=^|!_bs!%%a"<nul & >nul !_p!
set /p "_str="<nul & echo/ & exit /b
```

---

> - Alguns comentários sobre código/execução ::

```bat
@echo off & setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion 

:: prepara o ambiente para execução setando variaveis para execução em looping ::
cd /d "%~dp0" && title >nul && title Q399493 & >nul 2>nul chcp 1252

:: seta o caminho para usar o wmic.exe no loop, seta o arquivo para salvar nome de usuário  :: 
for /f ^delims^=*^~ %%i in ('%__APPDIR__%\where wmic.exe')do set _wmic=%%~i
set /a "_cnt=0" && set "_p=pathping 127.1 -n -q 1 -p 50" && set "_usr_log=%temp%\tmp_usr_.log"

:: Cria variaveis para uso na busca e na execução da compílação c#/exe + tags :: 
for /f %%a in ('"prompt $h&for %%b in (0) do rem"')do set "_bs=%%a"
2>nul >nul del /q /f "%temp%\Rm_Acnt.cs" & 2>nul >nul del /q /f "!_usr_log!"
set "_csc=%windir%\Microsoft.NET" & set "_where=%__appdir__%where.exe" & set "_path=."
set "_arg=/t:exe /out:"%tmp%\Rm_Acnt.exe" "%tmp%\Rm_Acnt.cs" /platform:anycpu /unsafe+ /w:0 /o /nologo"

:: Coleta e salva os nomes dos usuários em arquivo para uso em loop for + c#/exe  :: 
!_wmic! /append:"!_usr_log!" useraccount where (status='ok') get name /format:list|findstr .>nul


:: gera código em C# (C sharp), que será usado na execução para remover o acento :: 
cd /d "%temp%" && >"%temp%\Rm_Acnt.cs"^
    (
     echo/using System;namespace SO_BR_Q399493 ^{class Program ^{static void Main^(string[] args^)^{^{
     echo/byte[] tempBytes; tempBytes = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding^("ISO-8859-8"^).GetBytes^(args[0]^);
     echo/string asciiStr = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString^(tempBytes^);Console.Write^(asciiStr^);^}^}^}^}
    )

:: busca o compilador C# (csc.exe) no sistema, e o usa para compilar o código em C# criando o executável     ::
:: lê arquivos com nomes dos usuários faz chamada do label :^] que vai executar C#/exe que remove os acentos ::
for /f  delims^=^ eol^=* %%i in ('!_where! /r "!_csc!" "csc.exe"^|findstr /lic:"k\v2\."')do "%%~i" !_arg!
2>nul >nul !_p! & for /f ^tokens^=2^delims^=^=  %%f in ('type "!_usr_log!"^|findstr .')do set "_str=%%~f" && call :^] 
2>nul >nul del /q /f "%temp%\Rm_Acnt.*" & 2>nul >nul del /q /f "!_usr_log!" & goto :eof


:: faz a conversão dos carateres nos nomes dos usuários e verifica se a pasta existe com nome sem acento existe  ::
:: vai criar caso não existe pasta, e emitir uma mensagem na excução já sinalizando se foi criada ou se existia  ::
:^]
for /f delims^=^ eol^=* %%B in ('Rm_Acnt.exe "!_str!"')do call cmd /v/c && cmd /v/c mkdir "!_path!%%~B" 2>nul && (
set "_msg=Usuario: "!_str!" Pasta Criada Em: "!_path!%%~B"" )||( set "_msg=Usuario: "!_str!" Pasta Existe: "!_path!%%~B"")
for /f delims^=^ eol^=* %%a in ('"cmd /u /c echo=!_msg!|find /v """')do set /p "=^|!_bs!%%a"<nul & >nul !_p!
set /p "_str="<nul & echo/ & exit /b
```

---

> - Código em C# usado na tarefa de remoção dos acentos:

---

```bat
using System;
namespace SO_BR_Q399493 
{
  class Program 
  {
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      {
       byte[] tempBytes; tempBytes = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-8").GetBytes(args[0]);
       string asciiStr = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(tempBytes);
       Console.Write(asciiStr);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Fonte: [Resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249087/how-do-i-remove-diacritics-accents-from-a-string-in-net/13155469#13155469) publicada no SO/en por [@azrafe7](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1158913/azrafe7)

---

**Obs.:** Considere a sugestão de se familiarizar um pouco com alguma linguagem 
 programação, como o **`C`**, **`C#`**, **`Python`**, **`PHP`**..., **`bat/cmd`** são muito limitados.

---

---

Comment: Eu fico realmente impressionado com  o trabalho que e a quantidade de código em suas respostas envolvendo .bat e dos. No entanto, acho que, justamente por conta desse tipo de código ser a resposta para a pergunta em DOS (.bat), elas deveriam vir acompanhadas pela sujestão de uso de alguma outra linguagem - o código necessário é a própria demonstração de que o .bat não é a melhor ferramenta para quase nenhum dos problemas.  (NB - estou comentando agora, não sou um dos downvoters)

Comment: eu não respondi com outra linguagem. Mas o propósito e ajudar as pessoas, não ajudar a se enrolarem ainda mais por não conhecerem outras tecnologias. Você responder com um  .bat correto que faz o serviço apesar de ser 120% impossível de manter, não impede que no texto você convide o autor a explorar outras tecnologias e inclusive adicione exemplos.

Comment: Nesse caso mesmo, o "trabalho pesado" é feito em C#, e o código do programa em C# em si, fica ofuscado por conta do escaping necessário, dentro do .bat.  Não seria mais educativo colocar uma outra sessão da resposta, com o código em c# limpo e identado, e as instruções para compilação e uso do mesmo?

Comment: E tem um motivo pra isso: em outras linguagens, uma tarefa como essa é feita por um programa 2 ordens de grandeza mais simples. Ou seja: com o mesmo esforço você faz um programa 100 vezes melhor! Você consegue fazer coisas incríveis com .bat - mas em geral, quem pergunta como fazer algo mais complexo em .bat é justamente por que não conhece alternativas. O negócio do site é tentar fazer as pessoas aprenderem mais para poder resolver seus próprios problemas.